# RegExp to find the last return in javascript code string

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following string

```
cont x = 10;
function foo() {
  return x;
  // ;; end of function ;; //
  /* here is a some text
     here too */
}

function bar() {
    return 10
}

return foo() + bar();

// ;;done;; //
/* yolo
   yolo
*/
```

As you can see this string contains javascript and I need to know if this string has a **return** at the end. But that final return (which is optional) can be followed by 0 or comments and 0 or more \n's AND should not be a return inside a function. The only thing I can think of is to strip all the comments and then have some regexp to check if the last line contains a return. Something like this:

```
myJsStr
    .replace(/\/\/[^\n]+/gm, ';')                  // remove comments which start with //
    .replace(/(\/\*.[^*\\]+\n*?\*\/)/gm, '')       // remote comments /* ... */         
    .replace(/\n\s{0,}/gm,';').                    // remove returns -> single line
    .replace(/;{1,}/g, ';')                        // remove duplications of ;
    .match(/(return)[^;]+;?$/)                     // check the last part
```

Any improvements on this?

Comment: Why not extract it from the AST using acorn or similar?

Comment: Thats new territory for me. Do you mean [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ast-parser)?

Comment: A tiny, fast JavaScript parser, written completely in JavaScript. - https://github.com/acornjs/acorn.

Try parsing a document using acorn and then log it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have a regular grammar. So you can't use regular expressions to break a string of valid javascript down into it's meaningful tokens.

If you really want to understand the extend of what you can do with regular expressions, checkout the [Chomsky Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#The_Chomsky_hierarchy) and understand that regular expressions can only match the simplest, regular languages.

If you want to have a quick laugh, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383793) and search the web for a good javascript parser you can use. And go on with your life.

PS Or as an exercise, you can write a recursive descent parser yourself... And you can even use regex in your implementation. But a finite list of applications of any regex, will not do the trick.